# how to mix multiple array in to one array in php

Tags: php

I am getting array from database but it creating multiple array. I need only one array from database. Now simply I want to create one array from multiple array.

I got array from database -

```
Array(
[0] => Array(
  [0] => 1
  [pro_ref_id] => 1
)
[1] => Array(
 [0] => 1
 [sale_ref_id] => 1
)
  [1] => Array(
  [0] => 1
  [item_id] => 1
)
)
```

Actually I want -

```
 Array(
   [0] => 1
   [pro_ref_id] => 1
   [1] => 1
   [sale_ref_id] => 1
   [2] => 1
   [item_id] => 1
)
```

My PHP code is -

```
$resultData = array();
$re=mysql_query("select pro_ref_id,pro_qty,pro_item from proforma_details where pro_ref_id IN($piid_str)");
while($re1=mysql_fetch_array($re))
{
$rq=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select sale_ref_id,proforma_invoice_no from proforma_invoice where pro_invoice_id='".$re1['pro_ref_id']."'"));

$rq1=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select sale_order_no from sale_order where sale_id='".$rq['sale_ref_id']."'"));

array_push($resultData,$re1);
     array_push($resultData,$rq);
     array_push($resultData,$rq1);
}
```

Comment: Please show your query and the table structure. Also, how to flatten an array has been asked and answered many times before and you should not have a problem finding how to do that by searching before asking.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: The index `1` seems to appear two times in your array, I'm guessing that's a paste mistake?

Comment: $re=mysql_query("select pro_ref_id,pro_qty,pro_item from proforma_details where pro_ref_id IN($piid_str)");
  
while($re1=mysql_fetch_array($re))
 {
  
  $rq=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select sale_ref_id,proforma_invoice_no from proforma_invoice where pro_invoice_id='".$re1['pro_ref_id']."'"));
 
  $rq1=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select sale_order_no from sale_order where sale_id='".$rq['sale_ref_id']."'"));
   
   array_push($resultData,$re1);
   array_push($resultData,$rq);
   array_push($resultData,$rq1);
  
  }

Comment: i am fetching using above code

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the result set to create another array:

```
$res = array();
foreach ($array as $row) {
  $res = array_merge($res, $row);
}
```

Comment: I have use array_merge but not getting actual output

Comment: What is the value of $res after you use my code snippet. It must be the array you were expecting

Comment: its a negative output.