# I want get one array from database records

Tags: php

I am fetching records from database but it return records in multiple array. I want only one array from database.

My PHP code -

```
$resultData = array();
$re=mysql_query("select pro_ref_id,pro_qty,pro_item from proforma_details where pro_ref_id IN($piid_str)");
while($re1=mysql_fetch_array($re))
{
  $rq=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select sale_ref_id,proforma_invoice_no from proforma_invoice where pro_invoice_id='".$re1['pro_ref_id']."'"));
  $rq1=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select sale_order_no from sale_order where sale_id='".$rq['sale_ref_id']."'"));
  array_push($resultData,$re1);
  array_push($resultData,$rq);
  array_push($resultData,$rq1);
}
```

I am getting array -

```
Array(
  [0] => Array(
    [0] => 1
    [pro_ref_id] => 1
  )
  [1] => Array(
    [0] => 1
    [sale_ref_id] => 1
  )
```

And actually I want -

```
Array(
  [0] => 1
  [pro_ref_id] => 1
  [1] => 1
  [sale_ref_id] => 1
)
```

Comment: **mysql_*** is **deprecated** use PDO or MySQLi!

Comment: Dont try to post same question multiple times.. If you didnt get answers or your question is closed then try to improve your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602869/how-to-mix-multiple-array-in-to-one-array-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `mysql_fetch_array()` use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

**Also mysql_* is deprecated use PDO or MySQLi**